# Can we drink the milk of the goat that is intended for Aqeeqah?

Tags: sharia, aqeeqah

I like to know whether it is permissible to drink the milk of a goat that is intended to be slaughtered for the purpose of performing Aqeeqah? Please provide authentic answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

best to my knowledge, yes, you can.

Why ?

- Aqeeqah isn't a fard or wajib something. It's sunnah from Rasul (PBUH).
- When it's completely okay eating the meat (from aqeeqah) for the parents (as well as distributing among the poor), why drinking the milk wouldn't?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the fatwa team](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=fatwa&tab=4) at Islamweb.net, the requirements for an *aqiqah* sacrifice [are the same as for those sacrificed for *Eid*](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=92278).  These requirements are listed in [a related fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&lang=E&Id=81799&Option=FatwaId) on the same site, however they do not include anything about milking.  In particular, there is no mention at all that the animal needs to be unmilked for the sacrifice to be accepted.

In regards to an animal to be sacrificed as *hadi*, Ali is reported to have said "He may drink of its milk anything that is surplus to the requirements of its young."  This report is quoted in `Provisions for the Hereafter (abridged)` ([Muhammad ibn Abdul-Wahhab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Abd_al-Wahhab)'s abridgement of [Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyyah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_Al-Jawziyya)'s classic text), however since it is not cited I cannot speak for its authenticity.

A similar report can be found in Malik's Muwatta, attributed to one of the *tabi'un*, and goes as follows:

> [If necessary, ride on your sacrificial animal, without burdening it, and if necessary, drink its milk after its young one has drunk its fill, and when you sacrifice it, sacrifice the young one with it.](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/408610)

To my understanding, the above isn't about the suitability or acceptability of the sacrifice itself, rather it assuades that the young animal has more right to its mother's milk.  Drinking milk therefrom would be permissible, but as always Muslims are expected not to unnecessarily burden animals (either the mother or her young) or cause them to suffer.